# Javascript regex, replace all characters other than numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to replace all the characters other than 0-9 in a string, using Javascript.

Why would this regex not work ?

```
 "a100.dfwe".replace(/([^0-9])+/i, "")
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need the `/g` modifier to replace *every* occurrence:

```
"a100.dfwe".replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
```

I also removed the redundant `i` modifier and the unused capturing sub-expression braces for you.  As others have pointed out, you can also use `\D` to shorten it even further:

```
"a100.dfwe".replace(/\D+/g, "");
```

Comment: @PrakashRaman: it means *match one or more of the preceding characters*.  It's not needed, but it will increase the performance of the regular expression slightly by reducing the number of replaces required.

Comment: (Technically this answer, answers the question, but fails on floats)
"123.456px".replace(/\D+/g, ""); --> 123456

Comment: @AaronSherman that's right—the question did say characters other than 0-9, meaning digits rather than integers or floats.  For the latter two, a different, more complicated regex is required, or possibly `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()`.

Comment: @AndyE - parseFloat is what I was looking for when I found this question and couldn't remember that method

Comment: as Aaron Shermon points out: "123.456px".replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, "");

Answer (score 24):

`\D` means “not digit”:

```
"a100.dfwe".replace(/\D/g, "")
```

Answer (score 8):

What about negative numbers:

Using Andy E's example works unless you have a negative number. Then it removes the '-' symbol also leaving you with an always positive number (which might be ok). However if you want to keep number less than 0 I would suggest the following:

```
 "a-100.dfwe".replace(/(?!-)[^0-9.]/g, "")    //equals -100
```

But be careful, because this will leave all '-' symbols, giving you an error if your text looks like "-a-100.dfwe"

Comment: He's not really talking about numbers, just groups of digits.  Anyway, your regex still matches the `-` because it's not at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because the character class `[^0-9]` (= anything but digits) with the repetition modifier `+` will only match one sequence of non-numeric characters, such as "aaa".

For your purpose, use the `/g` modifier as the others suggest (to replace all matches globally), and you could also use the pre-defined character class `\D` (= not a digit) instead of `[^0-9]`, which would result in the more concise regex `/\D+/`.

Comment: to understand it better
shouldn't the "a" and ".dfwe" come under a + group, because that is 1 and more.

Comment: `\D+` says "look for one or more non-digits", whereas `(\D)+` looks for one or more repetitions of the (same) non-digit, which is not what you want.
Now, whether you do `/\D/g` (replace every single non-digit), or `/\D+/g` (replace every sequence of non-digits) doesn’t really matter except possibly in terms of performance, which won’t be noticeable unless you process tens of thousands of strings.

Comment: ah thanks a lot. That explains things perfectly to me. Thanks !

Comment: The group has nothing to do with it.  `[^0-9]+` and `([^0-9])+` will both match the same strings, whether they're `aaa` or `abc`.  The one with the group just does some unnecessary capturing along the way.  The `/g` flag **is** the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
"string@! 134".replace(/[^a-z^0-9]+/g, " ");
```

this would return "string 134"

Answer (score 0):

Based off of @user3324764's answer - Make a prototype function and convert the number to a number.

```
String.prototype.extractNumber = function ()
{
    return Number(this.replace(/(?!-)[^0-9.]/g, ""));
};
```

**Example:**

```
"123.456px".extractNumber(); // 123.456
```