# replace " ' " with " "in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

My string is like this:

```
temp="'SE019','SR132','SC123'";
```

I use a function like:

```
temp.replace("'","");
```

But the result will be:

> **SE019','SR132','SC123'**

only the first quote is removed I need all the quotes to be removed

Comment: Info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: What is the type of `temp`? Is it an `Array` or `String`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript regex, replace all characters other than numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309278/javascript-regex-replace-all-characters-other-than-numbers)

Comment: That looks really invalid, a string separated by commas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a regex literal with the `g` (for global, meaning match *all* occurrences) option.

```
temp.replace(/'/g,"");
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a reoccurring character or substring you can also use split/join method:

```
temp.split("'").join("")
```

It's less obvoius what it does and may be considered premature optimization, but may be marginally faster (or slower :)) http://jsperf.com/regex-split-join