# .replace() function doesn't replace forward slash with backslash

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I want to change all slashes into one string and I can't find solution.
This is my code:

```
var str = 'some\stack\overflow', 
replacement = '/';
var replaced = str.replace("\", "/");
console.log(replaced);
console.log("I want to see this: some/stack/overflow");
```

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d4N9s/402/)

Comment: It's been asked and asnwered less than an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865402/replace-with-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: It's not duplicate, my problem is far away from that one.

Comment: It's phrased like your problem was "`str.replace` only replaces the first occurrence" (which *is* part of your problem), while the hard part is replacing single unescaped `\ `.

Answer (score 2):

Try regular expressions with the global (g) flag.

```
var str = 'some\\stack\\overflow';
var regex = /\\/g;

var replaced = str.replace(regex, '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than using regex to replace every occurrence, not just the first one  as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865402/replace-with-in-javascript) 
(So, use `str.replace(/\\/g, "/");`)

You need to fix your string before passing it to JavaScript.

`"some\stack\overflow"` will be interpreted as `"somestackoverflow"`. `"\s" and "\o"` are treated as escape sequences, not "slash *letter*", so the string doesn't really have any slashes. You need `"some\\stack\\overflow"`. Why? that's why:

```
"s\tackoverflow" == "s    ackoverflow"

"stackove\rflow" == "stackove
flow"
```

"\s" and "\o" just happen to not mean anything special.

Comment: You won't get to the single `\ ` in `"stack\overflow"`, because it's disregarded by JS interpreter as soon as it parses that string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'some\\stack\overflow'
```

^^ This is incorrect. Corrected string is-

```
var str = 'some\\stack\\overflow'
```

Also, use global regular expression.

```
var replaced = str.replace(/\\/g, "/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

your `str` contains only one `\\` group, you try to replace only `\\` so is normally to see something like `some/stackoverflow`, so your code is :

```
var str = 'some\\stack\overflow' // your code
```

and `str` must be

```
var str = 'some\\stack\\overflow'
```

then will works

Answer (score 0):

Try Some Thing like this:

> var str = 'some\stack\overflow';
>
> replacement = '/';
>
> replaced = str.replace("\", "/");
>
> console.log(replaced);
>
> console.log("I want to see this: some/stack/overflow");