# Regex - javascript Replace all non-numerics

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I've seen this question asked a few times ([here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309278/javascript-regex-replace-all-characters-other-than-numbers)), and despite my best attempts to replicate, and reading up on regex, this doesn't seem to work:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    new_number = $("#the_input").val();
    new_number = new_number.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '')
             // also doesn't work: (/\D/g, '')
    $("#result").html(new_number);
});
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fc35h/4/)

**The Goal:** On button click, collect value from input, remove NON-NUMBERS and output string inside a div.

**The Result:** When I put a number in, it comes out fine. When I put a NON-NUMBER & a NUMBER, or anything but a number it comes out blank. It seems to replace the whole string, and not just the matched characters.

Help?

Comment: because since the type of input is `number` when you enter a non numerical value it does not return a value, change the type to text and check - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3QZdp/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to allow non numerical values to be entered into the input field, change the type to `text` from `number`

```
<input type="text" id="the_input">
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3QZdp/)

Comment: That was it. I didn't realise .val() would consider that as a problem. To keep the spinner that normally comes with type=number inputs, I used the jquery ui spinner, and got the same result. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is that you are using a a `type="number"` `input`. [The standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html) requires the `value` in a `number` input to be a [floating-point number](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.float). If a non-floating point value is entered when you query `.value` the browser returns an empty string. In Firefox if you query `.value` and it has an invalid value the input will be given a red glow around it indicating that it is an invalid value, at present, other browsers I tested do not; they just fail silently.

This means that when the browser evaluates `new_number.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '')` it is actually evaluating `''.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '')`, which results in an empty string.

As the previous answer suggested you could fix this behavior by changing it to a normal `text` input.

Alternatively, instead of trying to sanitize the input with a regular expression, you could validate the field by checking if `.val()` returns an empty string and warning the user if it did:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    var new_number = $("#the_input").val(); // don't forget to use var or your variable will be an implicit global!
    if (new_number === '') {
        // warn the user here
    } else {
        $("#result").html(new_number);
    }
});
```

When troubleshooting things like this, checking to make sure the input was what you were expecting can save you a lot of headaches!

Comment: Hmmm... I'm a little curious as to the reason for the down-vote on this.

Comment: Thanks bud, I like the suggestion, however simply changing the type to text is more appropriate in my specific case. I'll keep your suggestion in mind for the future! Love ur work.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code to filter it:

```
String.prototype.filter = function(){
    return this.match(/([0-9])/g).join("");
};
```

Example:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    new_number = $("#the_input").val().filter();
    $("#result").html(new_number);
});
```

Comment: He wants to replace non-numerics.

Comment: Oh. It's a match.join not a replace. sorry.

Comment: The real problem was solved by @Useless Code, and Arun any way.

Comment: Please, explain if you downvote. Thus, @QuentinEngles, add a `@` before user name.

Comment: If didn't say you downvoted :) I just ask the people who downvoted to explain.

Comment: A few reasons for the down-vote... Your answer doesn't solve the root cause of the problem running `.match(/([0-9])/g).join("");` on an empty string still returns an empty string. Also using `match` and then `join` adds a lot of overhead converting the string to an array and then back into a string. For non-empty strings the code in the question works and I suspect it is also faster than this solution. Augmenting the prototype of `String` isn't always a bad thing to do  depending on the environment, but you should probably check if the method already exists before blindly overwriting it.