# Get text before the last br in div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mls

Hi Guys i have this in html

```
<div class="flexmls_connect__sr_address">
  <div class="flexmls_connect__ld_price">$9,000,000</div>
  Km. 16.5 Carr. Barra de Navidad, Villa Armonia Estate
  <br>
  Puerto Vallarta, JA
  <br>MLS# 11187
  <br>//NEED THIS NUMBER---- >5 beds &nbsp;|&nbsp; //AND THIS NUMBER---- >8 baths &nbsp;|&nbsp; 11836 sqft
  <br>
</div>
```

and this in jquery

```
    var baths = $(res).find('.flexmls_connect__sr_address').before('br').last().contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    }).text();
```

I need obtain the beds and baths, and for clearify not is my html code i obtain from a very old API and i cant change the HTML, i neee that values with only jquery or javascript. not neccesary with my answer all methos are welcome i only try many of theme and the last is get text before last tag br but any help is great, thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`before()` is a dom insertion method. Can do something like the following

```js
var specs = $('.flexmls_connect__sr_address').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $(this).text().indexOf('beds')>-1;
}).text().split('|').reduce(function(a,c){
    if(c.indexOf('beds')>-1){
        a.beds = /\d+/.exec(c)[0]
    }else if(c.indexOf('baths')>-1){
        a.baths = /\d+/.exec(c)[0]
    }
    return a
},{});

console.log(specs);
console.log('Property has ', specs.baths, ' baths and ', specs.beds, ' beds');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexmls_connect__sr_address">
  <div class="flexmls_connect__ld_price">$9,000,000</div>
  Km. 16.5 Carr. Barra de Navidad, Villa Armonia Estate
  <br>
  Puerto Vallarta, JA
  <br>MLS# 11187
  <br>5 beds &nbsp;|&nbsp; 8 baths &nbsp;|&nbsp; 11836 sqft
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Needs some fine tuning to make sure that text exists before trying to process it

Answer (score 0):

You have to find text node content:

In this sample is `//NEED THIS NUMBER---- >5 beds &nbsp;|&nbsp; //AND THIS NUMBER---- >8 baths &nbsp;|&nbsp; 11836 sqft` then remove all characters except numbers and | char with regex such as this:

```
var textNodeContent = '//NEED THIS NUMBER---- >5 beds &nbsp;|&nbsp; //AND THIS NUMBER---- >8 baths &nbsp;|&nbsp; 11836 sqft',
stripped = textNodeContent.replace(/[^0-9\|]/g, '');
// the result will be 5|8|11836
```

Comment: The problem is in the other text i got for exmple lattitude, longitud maps and many numbers how this way 1250000088122095|6|1338544 so i cant make that because i cant determinate what number i need :/

Comment: The result such as `1250000088122095|6|1338544` you can split it with `split` function in javascript and the final result will be an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you HTML follows the same format as in the example then you can achieve your goal by selecting the inner HTML of each `div.flexmls_connect__sr_address` block, and using `split()` at each `<br>`.  The text you need is always going to be the second last item in that list, and this in turn can be `split()` at each `&nbsp;|&nbsp;` like so...

```
$('.flexmls_connect__sr_address').each(function() {
    // get innerHTML and split into array
    var block = $(this).html().split('<br>');

    // split second-last line into array
    var line = block[block.length - 2].split('&nbsp;|&nbsp;');

    // report to console
    console.log(' beds:',line[0].trim());
    console.log('baths:',line[1].trim());
    console.log(' sqft:',line[2].trim());
    console.log('----');
});
```

As mentioned [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9309318/4746328), you can then use regular expressions to grab just the number from each item in `line` as needed. I.E..

```
var beds = line[0].replace(/\D+/g, "");
```

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming the information is available after the 3rd "break" tag in div."flexmls_connect__sr_address" :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('flexmls_connect__sr_address')[0].getElementsByTagName("br")[2].nextSibling.data.split("|");
```

Here's the response that you would get ["5 beds  ", " 8 baths  ", "  11836 sqft↵  "]