# how to identify and store number in variables present in String in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, split

let's say i have a string in format like 
1."`Amount is between 5000 and 10000`" 
2. "`Amountbetween5000 and10000`" 
3."`5000 Amountbetweenand10000`" 
4."`50001000   amount`" 
 
 then i need to store 5000 and 10000 in 2 variables let's say  a and b 
if no number found then value of a and b will be 0

**string can or cannot have space between Words**

Comment: `string.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);`

Comment: have a look at this [replace all alphabets from string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9309318/2417602)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```
var numbers = string.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
```

> `\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
>
> > `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>
> `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)

Here in example, handled case if no match is found.

```js
var string = "Amount is between 5000 and 10000",
  numbers = [];

var arr = string.match(/\d+/g);
if (arr != null)
  numbers = arr.map(Number)

console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: _if no number found then value of a and b will be 0_ -- This will not be handled by this code.

Comment: for 50001000   amount  string 50001000undefined is coming dor document.write

Comment: @Shrey, `50001000` is a single number

Comment: @Satpal what is  there is only 1 number or no number at all ?

Comment: @AkhilJain, _no number at all_ `arr` will be `null` otherwise `arr` will have integers 1,2,3 whatever is present in string